# Ошибка запуска phppgadmin через openserver

Tags: php, postgresql, openserver

При запуске phppgadmin через openserver возникают ошибки:

```
Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 514001.99999999994 to int loses precision in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 175

Deprecated: Return type of ADODB_Iterator_empty::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2747

Deprecated: Return type of ADODB_Iterator_empty::next() should either be compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2752

Deprecated: Return type of ADODB_Iterator_empty::key() should either be compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2742

Deprecated: Return type of ADODB_Iterator_empty::valid() should either be compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2737

Deprecated: Return type of ADODB_Iterator_empty::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2733

Deprecated: Return type of ADORecordSet_empty::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2787

Deprecated: Return type of ADODB_Iterator::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2823

Deprecated: Return type of ADODB_Iterator::next() should either be compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2828

Deprecated: Return type of ADODB_Iterator::key() should either be compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2818

Deprecated: Return type of ADODB_Iterator::valid() should either be compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2813

Deprecated: Return type of ADODB_Iterator::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2808

Deprecated: Return type of ADORecordSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in D:\Program\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php on line 2904
Virtual Class -- cannot instantiate
```

Как решить их?

Comment: так вы же сами и написали (или откуда-то скопировали), английским по серому, что нужно сделать.

Comment: Ничего не написано, мне нужно решить эти ошибки именнно в openserver

Comment: во-первых, это не ошибки, а информационные сообщения. во-вторых, прочтите внимательнее любую из приведённых вами строк. там написано, что надо сделать, чтобы эти сообщения не выводились.

Comment: у вас 8 версия php. Код phadmin сделан для 7. Чтобы предупреждения не выводились, можно в настройках php выключить отображение Deprecated сообщений